# Buying a new computer

Tags: macos, mac, windows, pc

I'm gonna buy a new computer, but need some help choosing.

[I was aiming for a desktop from this shop: https://www.chip7.pt/desktop/35176-doit-gamer-i5-8400-chip7-doit-g.html#/9-perifericos-com_perifericos/49-ssd-ssd_240gb/37-grafica-nvidia_gtx_1060_3gb/8-so-sem_sistema_operativo](https://www.chip7.pt/desktop/35176-doit-gamer-i5-8400-chip7-doit-g.html#/9-perifericos-com_perifericos/49-ssd-ssd_240gb/37-grafica-nvidia_gtx_1060_3gb/8-so-sem_sistema_operativo)

And I wanted one for work and gaming too.

I want a stable one and I have a budget of around 1150€.

I've thought about a mac, but I don't think it's that good for gaming, is it?

I'm a programmer, so I also wanted that pc to be good for programming stuff.

Any Ideas?

Comment: As a programmer, you should be more than capable of working out exactly what you need....

Comment: The site you want for questions like this is [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  That said, you need to be more granular (much more detail) with your requirements.  "Gamer" is very broad - you need to describe the types of games.  "Programmer" is also extremely broad.  Are you doing CSS styling or are your data modeling/mining?  The difference being, the first can be done on an iPad and the latter I would recommend a workstation.  Before anyone can recommend anything, **you** need to define what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your budget the only thing you can get is the cheapest [MacBook Air for $1000](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-air?product=MQD32LL/A&step=config#).

It has a 1.8Ghz Core i5 with 8GB of Memory and 128GB SSD.

Programming is almost never a problem. You can code modern day things on 10 year old computers without a problem. Can you run the program? Maybe not. But you can code with them.

Gaming is a very general term? Are you play flash games on the internet like Pac-Man or are you playing games like GTA V?

If it’s the latter then this computer is not going to handle well. Will it run the game? Yes. Will it be really slow? Yes. Is the frame rate going to suck? Yes.

Additionally 128GB is not enough for video games that are going to be 60GBs per game.

If you playing only flash games then your fine.

**I would not suggest purchasing this computer for your needs.** For what you want it’s going to cost more no matter where you go.

**For future reference this is not the place to ask these types of questions. Contact Apple reps directly and they will walk you through what you want/need.**